# How does a rank 2 matrix with dimensions 3x2 differ from a full rank 2x2 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand both produce a 2d plane, and the 3x2 matrix spans a subset of R3, but what does this mean? What extra information is provided?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of information are you considering? A $2\times2$ matrix can be described with $4$ reals ($4$ degree of freedom), while a $3\times2$ has $6$ degrees of freedom: that's more information.
Geometrically, two noncollinear vectors in the 2D plane span the whole plane, end of story. In 3D, two noncollinear vectors span a plane among infinitely many possible planes: it's the plane orthogonal to the vector product of the two vectors.
On the other hand, to describe a point on one of those planes (either in 2D or 3D space), you need only two coordinates in both cases.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just learning this material, we've just been dealing with real numbers but from what I was understanding about the rank of matrices I wasn't able to visualize what the extra numbers in the 3x2 matrix signified.

You've made it all a lot clearer for me :)